# SQL Server 2014. Intellisense stopped working

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, sql-server-2014

It just stopped to popup complete the word options (I use SQL Server 2014 Management Studio).

What I did to fix it:

- I tried to refresh the cache (ctrl+shift+R),
- I checked if it is enabled,
- I have set the maximum script size of 5 MB,
- I disconnected and connected back,
- I checked if SQLCMD Mode is off.

I did everything I could find on this issue on the Internet. Nothing helps.
It. Just. Doesn't. Work.

What do I miss? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

The Intellisense didn't work only in one session. I have no idea why. In all other sessions it works fine.

Comment: Never used 2014, so can't I help.  but you can try ApexSQL Complete (free) or redgate SQL Prompt (expensive but very much worth it)

Comment: @Esh I'm currently taking SQL Database administration course, where we use this program for studying, so I'm kind of stuck with it.

Comment: Have you checked this? Troubleshooting IntelliSense (SQL Server Management Studio):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173434.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: In visual studio when it happens (c#), usually a rebuild of the project or sometimes removing the debug folder and restart of VS can help. I think it is has something to do with the compiler getting stuck somewhere.
not sure if you have such things there in SSMS 2014, but if you do, try to delete every possible file that you think won't damage the IDE and see if it helps after you restart it.  can't help much other than that.

Comment: @MangalPardeshi, yes, I did.

Comment: @Esh, I'm very new to this software, so I'm not sure which file is OK to delete and which one is not... Don't want to break things..

Comment: Another one,maybe this will help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2897539

Comment: @MangalPardeshi can't apply this cumulative update - it says my version is greater then the update is built for.